# Yii - Highcharts - Cannot show Y values

Tags: php, yii, highcharts

I'm using the Yii Highcharts extension, i can show X's values but cannot show the Y's values.
My Highchart widget code is:

```
$user = Yii::app()->user->id ;
$xAxis =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('data')
            ->from('teste')
            ->where('Utilizador_idUtilizador=:ut', array( ':ut'=>$user))    
            ->queryColumn();

$yAxis =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('racio')
            ->from('teste')
            ->where('Utilizador_idUtilizador=:ut', array( ':ut'=>$user))    
            ->queryColumn();

$this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget',array(
        'options' =>array(                         
            'title' => array('text' => 'Progressão'),
            'xAxis' => array(
                'categories' => $xAxis,                  
            ),
            'yAxis' => array(
                'title' => array('text' => 'valor'),                       
            ),
            'series' => array(
                array('name'   => 'Racio','data'   => $yAxis,'shadow' => false,
                )
            )
        )        
));


print_r($yAxis);
```

When i `print_r($yAxis)` it shows :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 1 [5] => 0 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 )
```

if i use a static array:
 `$yAxis = array(1,2,3,4,1,0,1,1);` it works and When i `print_r($yAxis)` it shows :
 `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 1 [5] => 0 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 )` , its the same array ! why the dynamic array doesn't work ?

Can anyone help me ?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm thinking the two $yAxis are similar and not entirely the same. Instead of typing the print_r results, can you copy and paste them to do a comparison?

Comment: I, thanks for your time. Can you be more specific? i dont understand what you are asking me to do, sory.

Comment: Can you copy and paste what you got for print_r($yAxis) instead of typing it?

Comment: i figured out what the problem was, the array received from the DB had string values... 
Thank you for your time :)